# IBM 437 windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

i used ionic.zip.dll Silverlight in my application Windows phone 7.1
but i had this exception "'IBM437' is not a supported encoding name."when i tried 
to use ZipFile.Read(stream);
any one have idea how i can resolve this ?
thank you in advance

Comment: Use a more modern version of a zip utility that uses utf-8 instead of the ancient IBM-PC code page.

Comment: have you any link of modern version for Windows phone thank you